# 'Rollup' function documented but absent from WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I need to manually perform the query that populates the ACTIVITIES tab of the Social Pane, the MSDN states that the `Rollup` function should do exactly that

[image]

It's also documented, with parameters and such

[image]

But if I try to invoke it... it's not there

[image]

What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's only available in version 8.2 of the api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481567.aspx#bkmk_820

Here's the relevant part of the linked page:

[image: Rollup Function was added in 8.2]

Comment: I missed that when checking the exact same page... Oh well, looks like the MSDN sometimes contains blatant lies ("Applies to: CRM 2016"... you wish). I added a screenshot so others won't have to click through the link.